# Assign User Id explicitly

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm hosting a `WebChat` where my JS code looks like,

```
var user = {
    id: params["userid"] || "myuser",
    name: params["username"] || "You"
};
```

After the WebChat is displayed, the user is presented with an option to SignIn. User completes the sign in process using Azure AD and state is updated with appropriate JWT token. So now the bot knows the actual user and his/her identity.

Is there any way to override `myuser` with the identity received from AAD? This will help maintain activities & state with specific user identity instead of storing all activities/state using `myuser`

Comment: No way and you don't want to because (1) how would bot connector know who to route back to and (2) how would you know who the message came from. You can use Bot State or your own DB to correlate IDs.